# Python: How can I test for a relatively straight line in a series of cubic lines?

Tags: python, math, statistics

I have a collection of curved lines, representing the third degree polynomial line of best fit for some datasets.

I want to differentiate relatively flat lines, filtering these plots, for further analyses.

For example I want to filter subplots 20935, 21004, 21010, 18761, 21037.

How can I do this, with a list of floats as input for these lines?

(using Python 3.8, Numpy, Math, mathplotlib in an anaconda env)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have got a list of *x*s and their respective *y*s, you can compute the slope for each point and check if the slope is always a constant value.

```
threshold = 0.001 # add your precision here. zero indicates a perfect straight line
is_straight_line = True
slope = (y[1]-y[0]) / (x[1] - x[0])
for i, (xval, yval) in enumerate(zip(x[2:], y[2:])):
  s = (yval - y[i-1]) / (xval - x[i-1])
  if abs(s - slope) > threshold:
    is_straight_line = False
    break

print(is_straight_line)
```

if you need the computation to be efficient, you should consider using numpy instead.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge of first-year calculus is assumed. There's a geometric property called "[curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Plane_curves)" that basically determines how much a shape bends at a certain point (really the inverse of the radius of the osculating circle at that point).

We can use [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Graph_of_a_function) to develop a formula for a cubic function with coefficients `[a, b, c, d]` at x = `x`.

```
def cubic_curvature(a, b, c, d, x):
    k = abs(6*a*x + 2*b) / (1 + (3*a*x**2 + 2*b*x + c)**2) ** 1.5
    return k
```

More general algorithms can be created for any polynomial, possibly with assistance from the `sympy` library depending on your needs.

With this in mind, you can set some threshold for curvature that determines whether the cubic is "straight" enough given its coefficients (I believe `scipy` or similar should be able to give you these from a list of points) and the x-value to be evaluated at (try the median independent variable).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I have yet to teach myself first year calculus. Might do that, and try the slope methodology in the meantime.

Comment: I tried this methodology and the median independent variable unfortunately did not filter out the straight lines. My idea is to try and identify the local minima and maxima of the curve/s for each dataset, then running your cubic curvature function to filter straight lines. Is there any chance in baby steps you would know how to do this? (or even if I'm on the right track?)

Comment: Hmm, I see that this will actually return a low value if the line is straight but not flat. Perhaps not what you're looking for, try fvall's solution?